# Editing multiple feature classes contained in feature dataset using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, feature-dataset

I have two feature classes contained inside a file geodatabase feature dataset.
One is point and one is polygon.
When I turn on editing mode for one of them, the other is editable as well.

Assuming that is the correct behavior by ArcMap, is that one of the advantages of using a feature dataset?

Comment: Nasty surprises possible. To prevent it, I use 'make this only selectable layer' option.

Comment: @FelixIP I think that even with that set, you need to take care with what is turned on for display because a polygon might be selected in only one layer but can clip through others that are also visible,

Answer (score 2):

I would not class this as an advantage of using a feature dataset over other types of workspace.

When you Start Editing in ArcMap what becomes available for you to edit is everything in a single workspace. A workspace may be a folder (of shapefiles), a geodatabase or a feature dataset within a geodatabase.

This is documented in [About edit sessions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-edit-sessions.htm) where it says:

> When you want to edit, you need to start an edit session, which you
>   end when you're done. Editing applies to a single workspace in a
>   single ArcMap data frame, where a workspace is a geodatabase or a
>   folder of shapefiles.

Comment: Thank you PolyGeo. Just to clarify: with my experience with shapefiles, you can only edit one at a time (meaning, you need to stop edits on one shapefile to edit the other). But you're saying that if I start an edit session of a feature class contained inside a geodatabase I will be able to edit all the feature classes inside that GDB without stopping my edit. Is that correct? Is that true for shapefiles contained inside a folder?

Comment: Please test using a folder of shapefiles again.  I think you will find that they are all editable without stopping and re-starting editing.